# Custom Windows Service conflicting with Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Tags: ssis, windows-services, oledbdataadapter

I have an SSIS package that uses the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider to read information from tab delimited text files. There is a script task in the package that has some code like so:

```
DataTable dtFiles = new DataTable();
string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileInfoLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=NO;FMT=TabDelimited\"";

OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM RepairFiscalYears.txt", connStr);
adapter.Fill(dtFiles);
```

This package runs as a local user, lets say UserA. Recently, a co-worker created a Windows Service on the same box the SSIS package runs on. The service's "Log on As" is set to the same UserA as the SSIS package runs. Now when I try to run the SSIS package I get the following error on the adapter.Fill(dtFiles) line.

```
EXCEPTION THROWN: 12/31/2014 3:04:06 AM
Unspecified error
Source: Microsoft Access Database Engine
HelpLink: 
StackTracee:    at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
   at ST_ee4c7bf65c87474397e28ea0f96c53d9.ScriptMain.Main()
```

If I stop the service and run the package it works fine. If I re-start the service and run the package it fails so I can easily reproduce the issue. Why does a Windows Service running under the same user as the SSIS package cause this conflict with the OLEDB provider?

Keep in mind that the Windows Service does nothing related to the package, i.e. doesn't read/write from any of the same locations/files/etc.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is the service using the Ace provider as well? Does it run in the same 32 or 64 bit space as your packages?

Comment: It does not use the Ace provider. I am not sure what you mean by "run in the same space".

Comment: It was a stretch but drivers come in 32 and 64 bit flavors. You'll run into this with SSIS as a package will work one way but not the other. I was speculating that perhaps the service running forced the SSIS execution to be in 64 bit space and it fails because there's not a driver available. Turning the service off allows a "clean" run which can then use 32 bit space.

Comment: They are both 64 bit.

Comment: I'd open an issue with Microsoft.  Another stretch, but does the web service DO anything to "UserA"?  Though even if it did, I think you would get a recognizeable error, and not "Unspecified".   This makes me think there is a bug in the way threading is being handled or something equally murky.

Comment: I've decided to use a StreamReader and some code to load my DataTable from the tab delimted text file. This way I can get rid of the Ace provider all together. Thanks all.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Once i configured "log on as" to be the same as the one behind proxy account for SSIS, there were these unexpected problems with jobs that used Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider.